# How to select multiple attributes along with grouping operation in Relational Algebra Queries?

Tags: relational-algebra

Say I have a table called T with attributes a1, a2, a3, a4, a5. Now I want to convert the below from SQL query to relational algebra query.

```
SELECT a1,a2,a3, COUNT(a4) AS counta4 FROM T GROUP BY a1;
```

When I try to do this in relational algebra as follows,

```
RENAME (a1,counta4) (a1 GROUPING COUNT a4 (T))
```

the result relation will only contain a1 and counta4 as its attributes.

But I want to include all a1,a2,a3,counta4 as the result relation's attributes.

How to achieve this in relational algebra using only SELECT, PROJECT, RENAME, UNION, INTERSECTION, MINUS, CROSS PRODUCT(CARTESIAN PRODUCT), JOIN, DIVISION, GROUPING operations?

---

For instance, let's say table T is the AUTHOR table and its attributes are as follows.
AUTHOR(**authorID**,**articleUrl**,firstName,lastName,articleTitle,articleWordsCount)

Now I want to select firstName,lastName, and the number of articles each author wrote.

So my SQL query will be,

```
SELECT authorID,firstName,lastName,COUNT(articleURL) AS numberOfArticles FROM AUTHOR GROUP BY authorID;
```

The syntax for GROUPING:
`<grouping attributes> GROUPING <function list> (Relation)`
`<function list>` is `<Aggregate function> <attribute name>` like pairs.

Reference: Fundamentals of Database Systems (7th edition) by Elmasri (Ramez Elmasri) & Navathe (Shamkant B. Navathe) - page 260 (8.4.2 Aggregate functions and Grouping)

Link: https://www.auhd.site/upfiles/elibrary/Azal2020-01-22-12-28-11-76901.pdf

The above example as a relational algebra query,

```
RENAME (authorID,numberOfArticles) (authorID GROUPING COUNT articleUrl (AUTHOR))
```

The result relation of this relational algebra query will have only authorID and numberOfArticles as the attributes but I need all the attributes mentioned in the SQL query which are authorID, firstName, LastName, numberOfArticles.

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't make any sense: you `GROUP BY a1`. So for each grouping, what value of `a2, a3` do you expect, and why?

Comment: There are many variants of "relational algebra"; many do not include any grouping ability; those that do have specific syntax for that variant. I've not seen a variant with a keyword `GROUPING`. So which variant have you been told to use, and what is its syntax? (See also hundreds/thousands of StackOverflow questions asking about grouping in relational algebra.)

Comment: @AntC I edited the question. Hope the question is more clear now. 
In the edit, I have mentioned the SQL query with an example and the GROUPING syntax.
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Put what is needed to ask in your post, not just  at a link or in a book. You need to give the syntax & semantics of the operators you use & a definition of what their notion of a relation is. PS Don't add "EDIT"s, edit your post to the best presentation as of edit time. PS The answer involves join, but you haven't defined your join operator(s) either. PS Use text, not image/links, for text.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you want T natural join the renamed grouped T.

Comment: @philipxy I got it now. So I need to do something like this. 

PROJECT authorID,firstName,lastName,numberOfArticles ((RENAME (authorID,numberOfArticles) (authorID GROUPING COUNT articleUrl (AUTHOR))) NATURAL JOIN AUTHOR)

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I didn't post an answer, I commented in good faith. Your post is not clear enough to  answer in detail. I should be closed (have answers blocked) until edited to be clear. Q&A here are for all time & all people, please consider editing your post to improve it [ask] & if you think you have an answer consider posting a (good) answer post [answer]. [help] [meta] [meta.se] PS For code questions give a [mre].